# Javascript Dynamically addEventListener and Node Reference

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

This works (in Firefox) ...

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/myJS.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Javascript file (called myJS.js for convenience)

```
window.onload = function()
{
    CreateInputTable();
};

CreateInputTable = function()
{
    var tbl = document.createElement('table');
    var tbo = document.createElement('tbody');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td1 = document.createElement('td');
    var ib = document.createElement('input');
    ib.setAttribute('type', 'text');

    var tdID = "c1"; // Cell reference

    if (ib.addEventListener)// all browsers except IE before version 9 - see http://help.dottoro.com/ljeuqqoq.php
        {
            ib.addEventListener('change', foo, false);
        }
    else// IE before version 9 - see http://help.dottoro.com/ljeuqqoq.php
        {
            ib.attachEvent('change', foo, false);       
        };

    td1.appendChild(ib);
    tr.appendChild(td1);

    var td2 = document.createElement('td');
    td2.setAttribute('id', tdID);
    td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hello world"));
    tr.appendChild(td2);

    tbo.appendChild(tr);
    tbl.appendChild(tbo);
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(tbl);
};

function foo (){
    if (document.getElementById("c1"))
        {
        document.getElementById("c1").appendChild(document.createTextNode(" and goodbye"));             
        }
};
```

However, I want to pass the cell reference "c1" to the event listener dynamically.

If I understand it correctly, I cant change the call to ...

```
ib.addEventListener('change', foo(tdID), false);
```

because the parentheses will return the return value of `foo`, not `foo` as a function.

However, I can get it to work by changing the declaration of tdID to

```
this.var tdID = "c1";
```

... and foo to

```
function foo (){
    if (document.getElementById(tdID))
        {
        document.getElementById(tdID).appendChild(document.createTextNode(" and goodbye"));             
        }
};
```

If I understand it correctly, it works because `foo` is called within `CreateInputTable`, which means that it can see the this variables in `CreateInputTable`.

However, this won't give me what I want because I want to create a second row with a new value for tdID. The above example seems to simply hard code the cell reference into `foo`.

How can I dynamically pass the cell reference to `foo`(in Object Oriented style)?

Comment: *(in Object Oriented style)* there is nothing "object-oriented" inside your code so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An elegant way would be this:

```
function foo (tdID){
    return function(){
        if (document.getElementById(tdID))
        {
            document.getElementById(tdID).appendChild(document.createTextNode(" and goodbye"));             
        }
    }
};
```

Then you can actually write

```
ib.addEventListener('change', foo(tdID), false);
```

because the call to `foo(tdID9)` will return a function with the right number of arguments and "knows" the correct value for `tdID' because it is captured in the closure of the inner  function.

This technique is called [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).